# Converting OSM.PBF to Geopackage in CLI?

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr, sqlite, command-line, geopackage

I would like to refresh this [tutorial](https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/) for my purposes - background vector map in one file - just to load in QGIS.

My idea is a script doing this:

1. Import directly downloaded Openstreetmap PBF file (country PBF from Geofabrik) or cropped (selected region etc.) using ogr2ogr directly to GeoPackage or some temporary working file.
2. simplify the attribute data - if I need just a basic background map with labels I do not need many attribute data fields and can merge others.

Should I use some temporary file (like Sqlite) for the attribute data manipulation or can I do this with Geopackage directly using set of CLI commands?